# replacing invalid html special characters using preg_match with html special character codes

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $tr_no = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $ii = 0; //iterator;
    while($news = mysql_fetch_array($query))

        //replacing special characters
        $replacename = eregi_replace(" ",  "-", $news['3']);
        $pattern = array();
        $pattern[0] = '-';
        $pattern[1] = "'";
        $replace = array();
        $replace[0] = '&#45;';
        $replace[1] = '&#39;';
        $news['2'] = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$news['2']);
        $news['1'] = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$news['1']);
        echo "<div style='width: 600px;' align='center'>";
        if($ii % 2 == 0){
            echo "<div style='width: 290px; height: 350px; float: left; padding:5px;'><h3 style='color:#ff0000; font-size: 14px;'>".$news['2']."</h3><p style='font-size:12px;'>".$news['1']."...</p><p><a href=\"".$href ."/". $replacename ."/item/".$news['0']."\">read more...</a></p></div>";
        }
        if($ii % 2 == 1){
            echo "<div style='width: 290px; height: 350px; float: left; padding:5px;'><h3 style='color:#ff0000; font-size: 14px;'>".$news['2']."</h3><p style='font-size:12px;'>".$news['1']."...</p><p><a href=\"".$href ."/". $replacename ."/item/".$news['0']."\">read more...</a></p></div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        $ii++;
    }
?>
```

The code output strings from the database while looping, but some characters appear invalid in an html format, see details: http://ipaidabribenaija.com/newsletter2.php
I have also used `str_replace()` in place of `preg_replace()`, but the functions are not effective in this situation.

Please how can i achieve this task?

Comment: I think it's encoding problem. which one do you use?

Comment: It's probably an encoding issue...

Comment: I use UTF-8 encoding, what do i do?

Comment: @JosiahChinedu : ok, but what's about DB encoding?

Comment: @DonCallisto, its utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$str = mb_decode_numericentity($str, array(0, 0x10FFFF, 0, 0xFFFFFF), 'UTF-8');
```

ie

```
$news[2] =  mb_decode_numericentity($news[2], array(0, 0x10FFFF, 0, 0xFFFFFF), 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: after that then i can do the replacement?

Comment: the code doesn't show the invalid characters, that is, it doesn't convert them to html special characters

Comment: Actually what this code `$news[2] =  mb_decode_numericentity($news[2], array(0, 0x10FFFF, 0, 0xFFFFFF), 'UTF-8');` does is to hide the invalid characters showing, but it couldn't convert the characters.
I notice the invalid characters was from the database string outputted, then i use the window charmap to search for the for the ascii of the invalid character, but window can't recognize the characters that is causing the errors, then i replace the invalid characters with valid once,i.e, i editted the post again and replace does characters causing errors.

Thanks to you all for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If isn't an encoding/decoding issue, why don't you try with [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) php's function?

Comment: using $news['2'] = htmlentities($news['2']); $news['1'] = htmlentities($news['1']); am still getting the same error. Still showing this character �

Comment: @JosiahChinedu can you provide some details about $news['2'] or $news['1'] content ?